# Ionic 3: How to create responsive text and layouts for different screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to create an Ionic 3 app for two different screen sized devices. I tried using ion-grid but the text goes off the screen.

Comment: What code have you tried? Could you provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can troubleshoot?

Comment: Please add some screenshot or code that you have done or facing issue so we can guide based on that ref details.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#default-breakpoints  this is how the bootstrap works. You can customize further https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#customizing-the-grid